# print the duplicate lines only on fields 1,2 from csv file

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, csv, uniq

by the following command we can print the duplicate lines from file

```
uniq -d string file.txt
```

but how we can do it on csv file ?

we need to print the duplicate lines only on fields 1,2 from csv file - not include field 3

FS - ","

for example:

```
 spark2-thrift-sparkconf,spark.history.fs.logDirectory,{{spark_history_dir}}
 spark2-thrift-sparkconf,spark.history.fs.logDirectory,true
 spark2-thrift-sparkconf,spark.history.Log.logDirectory,true
 spark2-thrift-sparkconf,spark.history.DF.logDirectory,true
```

expected results:

```
 spark2-thrift-sparkconf,spark.history.fs.logDirectory,{{spark_history_dir}}
 spark2-thrift-sparkconf,spark.history.fs.logDirectory,true
```

second:

how exclude the duplicate lines from the csv file ( I mean to delete only the duplicate lines on fields 1,2

expected output:

```
 spark2-thrift-sparkconf,spark.history.Log.logDirectory,true
 spark2-thrift-sparkconf,spark.history.DF.logDirectory,true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]++; next} a[$1,$2]>1' file.txt file.txt 
spark2-thrift-sparkconf,spark.history.fs.logDirectory,{{spark_history_dir}}
spark2-thrift-sparkconf,spark.history.fs.logDirectory,true
```

Two file processing using same input file twice

- `NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]++; next}` using first two fields as key, save number of occurrences
- `a[$1,$2]>1` print only if count is greater than 1 during second pass

For the opposite case, simple matter of changing condition check

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]++; next} a[$1,$2]==1' file.txt file.txt 
spark2-thrift-sparkconf,spark.history.Log.logDirectory,true
spark2-thrift-sparkconf,spark.history.DF.logDirectory,true
```

Comment: clear and elegant syntax

Comment: is it possible to delete the lines without to create another file copy ? as "sed -i  or perl -i , etc "

Comment: can't think of a way to do it with two file processing like this... you can always do it manually by adding `> tmp && mv tmp file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

`cut` the first two fields, `uniq` them as you suggested and use the result to `grep` the lines in the original file:

```
cut -d, -f1,2 file.cvs |uniq -d|grep -Ff - file.cvs
```

If the file is not yet sorted, you have to sort it before the `uniq`:

```
cut -d, -f1,2 file.cvs |sort|uniq -d|grep -Ff - file.cvs
```

For the second question (inverted result), use option `-u` instead of `-d`:

```
cut -d, -f1,2 file.cvs |sort|uniq -u|grep -Ff - file.cvs
```

Comment: nice , is it possible to add another question - we need also to exclude the duplicate lines from the csv ( I mean to delete only the duplicate lines on fields 1,2 )

Comment: update question

Comment: answer updated.

Comment: from some reason after we created the new file without duplicate lines , i see still duplicate lines

Comment: example - ams-hbase-site,hbase.zookeeper.quorum,{{zookeeper_quorum_hosts}}
core-site,fs.defaultFS,true
ams-hbase-site,hbase.zookeeper.quorum,true
ams-hbase-site,hbase.zookeeper.quorum,{{zookeeper_quorum_hosts}}
core-site,fs.defaultFS,hdfs://hdfsha
core-site,fs.defaultFS,true

Comment: To use `uniq`, the lines are expected to be sorted. In your new example they are not. `sort` the file first.

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

-- *to print the duplicate lines only on fields 1,2 from csv file*

```
awk -F, '$1==f1 && $2==f2{ printf "%s,%s,%s\n%s\n", f1,f2,f3,$0 }
        { f1=$1; f2=$2; f3=$3 }' <(sort -t, -k1,1 -k2,2 file.txt)
```

The output:

```
spark2-thrift-sparkconf,spark.history.fs.logDirectory,{{spark_history_dir}}
spark2-thrift-sparkconf,spark.history.fs.logDirectory,true
```

---

-- *exclude the duplicate lines from the csv file (on fields 1,2)*

```
awk -F, 'f1 && f2{ if($1!=f1 || $2!=f2) { printf "%s,%s,%s\n", f1,f2,f3 } else next }
        { f1=$1; f2=$2; f3=$3 }' <(sort -t, -k1,1 -k2,2 file.txt)
```

The output:

```
spark2-thrift-sparkconf,spark.history.DF.logDirectory,true
spark2-thrift-sparkconf,spark.history.fs.logDirectory,{{spark_history_dir}}
```